# JQuery MVC4 $(document).ready(function is not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a complex MVC4 page, with already more than one use of $(document).ready

Everything works well.

But in this specific case, I can see in Firebug step by step the cursor jump directly to the last brace. Here is the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var ProjectId = GetURLParameter('ProjectId');
            var ContextType = GetURLParameter('ContextType');
            var ContextId = GetUrlParameter('ContextId');
            var Category = GetUrlParameter('category');
            var Schmurz = GetURLParameter('schmurz');
            if (Category)
            {
                var strMethodUrl = "/Tree/GetSelectedCategory?category=" + Category;
                $.get(strMethodUrl, receiveResponse);
            }

            function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
                var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var sURLVariables = sPageURL.sp('&');
                if (sURLVariable) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                            return sParameterName[1];
                        }
                    }
                }

                return '';
            }
        });               
</script>
```

It's exactly the same if I write this as below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var ProjectId = GetURLParameter('ProjectId');
            var ContextType = GetURLParameter('ContextType');
            var ContextId = GetUrlParameter('ContextId');
            var Category = GetUrlParameter('category');
            var Schmurz = GetURLParameter('schmurz');
            if (Category)
            {
                var strMethodUrl = "/Tree/GetSelectedCategory?category=" + Category;
                $.get(strMethodUrl, receiveResponse);
            }            
        });

        function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var sURLVariables = sPageURL.sp('&');
            if (sURLVariable) {
                for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                        return sParameterName[1];
                    }
                }
            }

            return '';
        }
</script>
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated, as I really don't see the reason for this, and need this code to work very soon.

Thanks!

Comment: put your function GetURLParameter before calling it 
<script>
function GetURLParameter(....

$(document).ready(function(){....

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint inside the function within the ready call? Without it you are only defining the function which is why it goes to the bottom.  With a breakpoint inside the function you can see it when it executes.  If it still doesn't execute then that is because the page may already be past the ready point and won't trigger again.

Comment: What is the actual question? You said the code works?

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes won't matter bc [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes Thank you!

Comment: @BernardG the second line of your questions says __"Everthing works well."__ How else should I interpret that?

Comment: @Mathletics by reading the line below: **BUT IN THIS SPECIFIC CASE....**

Comment: _in this specific case, I can see in Firebug step by step the cursor jump directly to the last brace._ Sounds like an issue with Firebug; is that your question? Or is the _code itself_ behaving differently from what you expect? I'm just trying to understand what problem you're having.

Comment: @BernardG glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Function calls are case sensitive. You are calling GetUrlParameter even though you have defined GetURLParameter. Also make sure all sURLVariables are named properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

         function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var sURLVariables = sPageURL.sp('&');
            if (sURLVariables) {
                for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                        return sParameterName[1];
                    }
                }
            }

            return '';
        }

        var ProjectId = GetURLParameter('ProjectId');
        var ContextType = GetURLParameter('ContextType');
        var ContextId = GetURLParameter('ContextId');
        var Category = GetURLParameter('category');
        var Schmurz = GetURLParameter('schmurz');


        if (Category)
        {
            var strMethodUrl = "/Tree/GetSelectedCategory?category=" + Category;
            $.get(strMethodUrl, receiveResponse);
        }


    });
```

In terms of when you define the function, both of these work:

http://jsfiddle.net/6qavvth8/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/6qavvth8/2/

Comment: This won't matter bc [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

Comment: @Mathletics It DOES matter... Sorry!

Comment: @bingo Thanks! Daniel put me on the right track first. Defining the function before calling it allow me to follow step by step and correct a few syntax errors (sURLVariable and sURLVariables, for example)

Comment: Yes, defining the function before or after makes no difference IF YOU HAVE NO ERRORS. But for Firebug, if DOES make a difference, and I would still be looking for them if I had not changed the order.